# Why Objects in ResponseDTO are empty?

Tags: servicestack

I'm new to ServiceStack so sorry if it is a noobish question. but even when I run default ServiceStack examples (downloaded from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/ ) I get empty DTO responses. for example when I call

```
/json/syncreply/Movies
```

I get this in response:

```
{"ResponseStatus":{},"Movies":[{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

As you can see number of Movies are correct (5 movies) but why they are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to add [DataMember] attribute to my ResponseDTO internal objects. How come they have dropped it on Service Stack Samples and documentation?